# Problem after navigation from a page to another

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, navigation, rendering

I am working on an IONIC app, where previously there was a terrible management and the code is really ugly.

First I am going to explain the path and then show the code.

The user should scan a QR. If the response is successful, the APP should redirect the user to another page where a confirmation of the previously shown QR Code will be displayed.
The problem I find here is that the page that should be redirected, renders directly behind the Home page.
The URL is updated showing the correct path.

Here are the code snippets:

**QRModal confirmation that should lead to the next page.**

```
const handleConfirm = async () => {
const containerList: any = [];
try {
  containers.map((container) => {
    containerList.push(container.id);
  });
  const response = await logisticsApi.selfAssign(containerList);

  if (response.success) {
    updateIsContainerScan(false);
    setLendConfig(containers);
    navigate.push('/self-assign');
    onDismiss();
    toaster.flashSuccess(t('SuccessfullyAdded'));
  } else {
    toaster.flashError(t('GeneralError'));
    onDismiss();
  }
  return;
} catch (error) {
  updateScanning(true);
  toaster.flashError(t('GeneralError'));
}
```

};

**This is the component that will be shown after the successful scan.**

```
const ConfirmationSelfAssign = ({ lendConfig }: ConfirmationModalProps) => {
  console.log(lendConfig, 'confirmation');
  const [showAlert1, setShowAlert1] = useState(false);

  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return (
    <>
      <Placeholder
        selfAssignConfirmation
        icon="assets/confirmationTick.svg"
        title={t('SelfAssignConfirmation', { total: lendConfig.length })}
      />
      <Cart confirmationModal key={lendConfig} items={lendConfig} />
      <Button onClick={() => setShowAlert1(true)} primary>
        Cerrar
      </Button>
      <ConfirmationAlert showAlert={showAlert1} />
    </>
  );
```

**Lastly, here is the AppRouter**. (I have added only the most relevant for this topic)

```
<Suspense fallback={() => <Loading />}>
      <IonReactRouter>
        <LastLocationProvider>
          <LinkListener />
          <IonRouterOutlet>
            <PublicRoute path="/" component={Pages.Splash} exact />
            <PrivateRoute as="customer" path="/customer" component={Pages.Home} exact />
            <PrivateRoute
              as="customer"
              path="/self-assign"
              component={Pages.ConfirmationSelfAssign}
              exact
            />
          </IonRouterOutlet>
        </LastLocationProvider>
      </IonReactRouter>
    </Suspense>
```

I don't know if what I have posted above will be enough description. If you still need more information, please, let me know.

I will be really grateful if someone is able to help me with this problem.

Comment: is ConfirmationSelfAssign a component or a Page? You should be navigating to Pages for Ionic to work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing useNavigate and using that?

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'

const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate("/self-assign");
```

Documentation for push and navigate difference:

`The Push action adds a route on top of the stack and navigates forward to it. This differs from navigate in that navigate will pop back to earlier in the stack if a component is already mounted there. Push will always add on top, so a component can be mounted multiple times.`

Comment: It is using react-router-dom v5.2.
Previous developers were using useHistory instead, which is what I am using here.

const navigate = useHistory()
navigate.push('/self-assign');